# How to create a subflavor (or variant of existing flavor) with minimal duplicated code?

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I am familiar with basics of flavors and dimensions, but not sure how to solve my problem.

Let's say I have 2 flavors in my app - GREEN and RED. They share common kotlin code and only differ in the look = they have their own resources folders with different colors and layouts.

Now I want to create something like a subflavor from GREEN - let's say GREEN_NOMENU, where the only difference against GREEN will be be disabling some menu items. 1-2 lines of code. Everything else is the same.

How to do this?

Creating a new flavor GREEN_NOMENU feels wrong, because that would also require copying all the resources from GREEN. I don't really like this, seems like a lot of duplicated files for 1 line of change in disabling some menu item.

Is it possible to create a flavor, which will inherit everything from another flavor?

**What's a proper way to manage minimal changes in between variants/flavors like this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple flavor dimensions and combine them. See the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#flavor-dimensions).

You could create another flavor `menu` and `nomenu` and assign the `menutype` dimension to it.

This would allow you to build your app with the version `greenMenu`, `greenNomenu`, `redMenu` and `redNomenu`.

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    debug {...}
    release {...}
  }

  productFlavors {
    red {
      dimension "color"
      ...
    }

    green {
      dimension "color"
      ...
    }

    menu {
      dimension "menutype"
      ...
    }

    nomenu {
      dimension "menutype"
      ...
    }
}
```

You can then also create subfolders for your code and resources with the combined flavors. For example, you can create a resource folder specifically for `greenNomenu` where you remove the menu items.